# Non root user is not able to open any ports

Tags: networking, python, port, non-root-user

I have an embedded Linux System built using Yocto. Just out of build, it only had a root user. I created a new user. This new user is not able to open any ports on the system even though they are greater than 1024.

For a quick test when I run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` as `root`, it just works.

```
~ # python -m SimpleHTTPServer
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

However, when I run it using the non-root user, it fails due to access issues.

```
~ $ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SimpleHTTPServer.py", line 235, in <module>
    test()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SimpleHTTPServer.py", line 231, in test
    BaseHTTPServer.test(HandlerClass, ServerClass)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 606, in test
    httpd = ServerClass(server_address, HandlerClass)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 414, in __init__
    self.socket_type)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 191, in __init__
    _sock = _realsocket(family, type, proto)
socket.error: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I tried different ports for this and non-root user can't open any of them.

My understanding is only root user can access ports < 1024 but other ports are usable by non-root users as far as they are free. However, I am not able to use any ports at all. Any pointers will be really helpful.

Comment: What happens when you `nc -lv 127.0.0.1 8000` (or another process that listens to a port)? Does it also deny permission?

Comment: It has a BusyBox based version of `nc` so doesn't support `-v` version.  Running `nc -l 127.0.0.1:8000` as non-root user gives `nc: socket: Permission denied` while with root user it just goes into wait mode.

Comment: But I think it is listening to the port with root user and since no -v option is supported, it doesn't show any message.

Comment: Is SELinux enabled?

Comment: I checked with `sestatus`,  it is disabled. `SELinux status:                 disabled`

Comment: I'd look at  AppArmor rules.

Comment: AppArmor service is not running on this board.

Comment: Can you give the output of this command? `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start` or else `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_unprivileged_port_start`. It's supposed to be 1024 not more.

Comment: For first command, I am getting `sysctl: error: 'net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start' is an unknown key` and for second, `cat: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_unprivileged_port_start: No such file or directory`. So, I think this is not set.

Comment: kernel version? `uname -r`

Comment: This is kernel version 3.18.

Comment: Also try netcat (nc) with an higher port just to check: 50000 and 65500 (so I can leave this idea beside)

Comment: `nc` is exiting with same `nc: socket: Permission denied` even at higher numbered ports.

Comment: Looking at kernel version, this key doesn't seem to be supported on this kernel.

Comment: Just means that's not the problem, but I'm out of ideas

Comment: Does systemd need to do anything while starting up for this to work as expected?

Comment: Whatever your system is doing, it's not a normal behavior. The normal behavior is that nothing is required for a normal user to listen on port 8000. So it's not about what's missing, but what has been done to it.

Comment: I think that is correct way to look at it. However, to trace it back to Yocto build, I don't know what to look for as I don't know what is exactly messed up here. So, it has become a chicken hen problem for me. Thanks for taking time to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a group `inet(3003)`, which was assigned to user but not to any new users. Once I add the non-root user to this group, they are able to open the ports and `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` runs just fine.

I was able to get to this specifics, by running  `/sbin/ifconfig` as non-root user. Running it specifically mentioned `inet` socket not being available and fiddling around for a bit led me to above solution.

Comment: OP forgot to mention the kernel is an Android kernel rather than just a Linux kernel, or a Linux kernel with Android patches. Here's the relevant feature: https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+/2038692b9acf7ae3054a35e879039ff062316bf0%5E!/ . It could have been found faster with this information.

Comment: It is a Linux kernel built using Yocto. However, looks like BSP provider added this patch on the Linux kernel. However I was not aware of posting it earlier. After digging further into it, I came to know it being a Android MAC feature. Thanks for the pointer.